# What is the procedure to find adjoint of linear transformation on infinite dimensional inner product space?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

What is the procedure to find adjoint of linear transformation on infinite dimensional inner product space? When in the procedure , we know that adjoint does not exist?

Answer (score 0):

Whatever the dimension is, the adjoint of a linear operator $T$ is defined by the following relation

$$\forall x, y \in H \ \langle Tx, y \rangle = \langle x, T^* y \rangle$$ This enables to compute $T^*$ on a Hilbert basis.